# Finding all urls in string including hyphens

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am looking for regex that would find all of the following urls:

hello.com
hello1.com
1hello.com
hello-1.com
hello-hi1.com
1hello-hi.com
h3ll0.com

I have tried a few different Regexs but nothing seems to be quite right.

```
regex = re.compile('\w+\.(com|org|net)')
data = regex.search(string)
url = data.group(0)
```

I want it to return all of the above urls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this part `(-\w+)*` in your regex which will allow it to have optional hyphen in the domain name part of your url. You can use this URL,

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*\.(?:com|org|net)
   ^^^^^^^^^ this allows the URL to have optional hyphen
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJiy4S/1)**

You should make the group non-capture unless you really need them as it improves its performance.

Answer (score 0):

Could try spliting the string by a '.' delimiter and then checking if the value is in a white list of say ['com', 'org', 'net', 'io' ....]

For example

```
whitelist = {'com', 'org', 'net', 'io'}
possible_url = 'hello.com'
if possible_url.split('.')[-1] in whitelist:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

using a simple regex can cause you to accidentally match words. for example simply using `[\w-]+\.(com|org|net)` [demo#1](https://regex101.com/r/OpjMKK/1) would meet your requirements but would miss all the other domains, miss sub-domains and match normal words.

This regex might be better suited `\b\w[-.\w]+\.(com|org|net)\b` [demo#2](https://regex101.com/r/OpjMKK/3)